# Return an object from a function and save to global environment R

Tags: r, function, return

I'm trying to return an object with a value 'alt_props' for all traits with the use of a function:

```
calc_palt <- function(x){

  s <- length(pvals[which(pvals[,x] < (5*10^-8))]) #how many significant p-values
  t <- sum(! is.na(pvals[, x])) #total amount of SNPs
  alt_props <- s/t  #calculation of alt_props

  b <- sum(! is.na(betas[,x])) #total amount of betas

  if((alt_props/b) < 30){
    alt_props <- 30     #ensure that alt_props is at least 30
    return(alt_props)
  } else {
       return(alt_props)
     }
}
```

alt_props should at least be 30, so when the calculated alt_props is lower than 30, that alt_props value should be changed to 30. When doing: (x (1:7) are the columns that represent the different traits

```
calc_props(1:7) 
[1] 30
```

I know that return() only returns one value, so this makes sense. However, I need to return an object with 7 values. Can anyone help me with this?

My data looks like this: (betas is similar)

```
pvals
       pval_g   pval_p pval_p.x pval_p.y   pval_m pval_m.x pval_m.y
 [1,] 6.0e-02       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
 [2,] 9.5e-01       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
 [3,] 1.2e-01       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
 [4,] 4.5e-12       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
 [5,] 3.9e-01       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
 [6,] 2.8e-01       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
 [7,] 5.1e-03       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
 [8,] 4.6e-02       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
 [9,] 4.8e-01       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
[10,]      NA       NA       NA       NA 0.701233 0.082081 0.137990
[11,]      NA 0.018110  0.23190  0.35680       NA       NA       NA
```

Comment: The posted code is not complete, there's a initial part missing.

Comment: @RuiBarradas thanks for noticing, i've added it now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the following is what the question asks for.
The original answer's code was completely changed after [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61590909/return-an-object-from-a-function-and-save-to-global-environment-r/61591335#comment108947926_61591335) by user [Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1412059/roland).

```
calc_props <- function(x, p.vals, betas){
  s <- colSums(p.vals < 5e-8, na.rm = TRUE)
  t <- colSums(!is.na(p.vals))
  b <- colSums(!is.na(betas))
  alt_props <- s/t
  alt_props[alt_props/b < 30] <- 30
  alt_props
}
```

The test uses matrix `pvals` twice, the second of them in place of the `betas`, which are missing from the question.

```
calc_props(1:7, pvals, pvals)
#  pval_g   pval_p pval_p.x pval_p.y   pval_m pval_m.x pval_m.y 
#      30       30       30       30       30       30       30
```

**Data in `dput` format**

```
pvals <-
structure(c(0.06, 0.95, 0.12, 4.5e-12, 0.39, 0.28, 0.0051, 0.046, 
0.48, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.01811, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.2319, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.3568, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0.701233, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.082081, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.13799, NA), .Dim = c(11L, 
7L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("pval_g", "pval_p", "pval_p.x", 
"pval_p.y", "pval_m", "pval_m.x", "pval_m.y")))
```

Comment: This calculation of `alt_probs` could be vectorized easily using `colSums`. Then we could do `alt_props[alt_props < 30] <- 30; return(alt_props)`.

Comment: This works when omitting betas. I forgot to add them to the calculation. It adas should have been `if (alt_props/b < 30)`. To check: is it correct if the only thing I change to the code (to incorporate betas) `calc_props(1:7, pvals, betas`  or should I change more? Unfortunately the output is always 30, as this is practice data and no alt_props > 30, so i can't check if the addition is working